# How to generate the Symbols file of a PowerBuilder program for dump analysis?

Tags: symbols, dump, powerbuilder

How to generate the Symbols file of a PowerBuilder program for dump analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running into a problem with a compiled PowerBuilder application?

I've never used the Microsoft debugger, however, I have used Dependency Walker and ran my app from within that environment.  Usually that helps us if we have missing deployables, etc.

If you need a stack dump, have you thought about running the app from the Run window and adding the /debug option after the name of the app?  That creates a call stack log that shows all your commands being called, etc.  Probably would get you what you need.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Dr. Watson (drwtsn32) to automatically create a crash dump when/if your application dies.

That said, the dump will usually only be useful if you are calling into native DLL's. Otherwise the stack will just include various PBVM calls that will be difficult to correlate back to actual source code lines.